# using jquery toggle to perform multiple actions

Tags: jquery, events, toggle

I am trying to have multiple events happen through a jquery toggle.  I want to show/hide an element as well as apply a style to the element underneath with the same click event.  any ideas? is this even possible?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
  $("p").toggle();},function(){
  $("#write").css("background-color", "yellow");
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bbelch/nGFzW/

Comment: so what is the problem

Comment: code posted here and in the fiddle is different, theres some typing error

Comment: never mind I figured it out <http://jsfiddle.net/bbelch/nGFzW/8/>

Comment: but thank you anyway Uttara

Comment: @user2234473, you should not attach multiple `click` handlers for one element. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want this. For more help I am there. Happy coding!!!

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $("button").click(function () {               
        var isVisible = $("#me").toggle().is(":visible");
        if (isVisible) {
            $("#change").css("background-color", "yellow");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#change").css("background-color", "red");
        }
    });
});

<html>
     <body>
        <button>Toggle between hide() and show()</button>
         <div id="me">show me then hide me </div>
         <div id="change">New Look</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("#redcover").toggle();
        $("#write").toggleClass('blrrrry', 1000);

    });
});
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6KfvR/1/)</kbd>